# Is there a way to open a tcp socket connection in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm currently developing a chrome extension. I would like to open a tcp socket to a url (for example `https://www.google.com`), with the goal of establishing a connection to send and receive data. Is there a way I can do this in Javascript? Is it also possible to maintain a connection to a url/server using websockets in Javascript?

Comment: Did you research JavaScript [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know if there's a way to achieve that with tcp sockets. I've tried connecting a websocket, for example using google url, but I can't do it. I've tried the following: ```var httpsWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.google.com:443");```, but I get error 400 Bad Request. Maybe some servers don't accept websocket connections?